# Matlab: meshgrid and surf (3D plot)

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate a 3D surface plot for x,y,z data using surf():

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(0.5:0.5:25, 0.5:0.5:45);
Z=(tand(y/2)*(1.84+x))*2;
```

but I get the following error:

> Error using  *  Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the element-wise product:

```
Z=(tand(y/2).*(1.84+x))*2;
surf(x,y,Z);
```